# How to pause previous audio function?

Tags: javascript, html

When I press the button, I want to play a song, when I press the second song a second time, and when the third one, the cycle repeats again, but the first song is shorter than the second one, and if you click many times, the long song plays simultaneously with its other copy. Is it possible to stop the previous music and move on to another?

Html:

```
< a id="Play">test< / a>

Script:


window.onload=function(){

let number = 0;

  var t;

document.getElementById('Play').addEventListener('click',function(){

  let audio = new Audio();

  if ( number == 0 ) {

    audio.src = '/assets/sound/test.mp3';

    number = 1;


  }

  else


  if ( number == 1 ) {

    audio.src = '/assets/sound/curious&loony.mp3';

    number = 0;


  }

  audio.autoplay = true;

});



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way.
How to:

```
<script>
    var i = 1, player = new Audio();
     player.src = "/assets/sound/sound1.mp3";
document.querySelector('#play-button').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  if (i === 1) {
    player.src = "/assets/sound/sound1.mp3";
    i = 0;
  } else if (i === 0) {
    player.src = "/assets/sound/sound2.mp3";
    i = 1;
  }
  player.play();
});

</script>

<a href="#" id="play-button">Play me harder</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sound.pause();
sound.currentTime = 0;
```

Use this for pause audio

Comment: Still comes simultaneously

Comment: Solve:

<script>
 var i = 1, player = new Audio();
     player.src = "/assets/sound/music1.mp3";
document.querySelector('#play-button').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
  if (i === 1) {
    player.src = "/assets/sound/music1.mp3";
    i = 0;
  } else if (i === 0) {
    player.src = "/assets/sound/music2.mp3";
    i = 1;
  }
  player.play();
});

</script>

< a href="#" id="play-button">Play< / a >